# Ubuntu 21.04 video mode fail after logout

Tags: nvidia

I've just installed Ubuntu 21.04.
When I select to "log out" my monitor says it can't display this videomode, no click or keypress I can think of changes anything, so I can't login again unless I push the reset button and do a full reboot.  System is using the recommended/proprietary/tested Nvidia driver 460.73.01 on a 2060 super card.
Logout worked fine in Ubuntu 20.04 / Nvidia 450.102.04
Do others have the same problem?

Comment: Please file a proper bug report for this issue.

Comment: Does this in 18.04 too. NVIDIA 465, Monitor has Dual HDMI input so I have 2 computers fed in, when I switch to other computer and back again it can no longer access video. Switching to TTY works and eventually after multiple keystrokes, I can get log-in screen again. Very unusual behavior.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: Reported using ubuntu-bug.